# Can my family apply for another UK visitor visa before their current one has not expired?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, uk-visitor-visa

I am trying to get my family to the UK for a 2-month stay with me. They have got their visa last week, however, due to some unforeseen circumstances, they are now only able to travel towards the end of their currently granted visa period. This means they will not be able to spend 2 months in the UK as we were originally planning. I was wondering if they can apply for another visa before their current visa expires on the grounds that they never used their current visa? Has anyone done this before? What are the chances of their application being successful?

**Update**

I managed to get a response from UKVI that my family can apply for another visa while their current visa is still running. This is on the basis that they have not travelled. I am not sure if I was very clear when I asked them the question in the first instance. This is because there was a limit to the number of words I could use to write up my question. I will give it another go

Comment: Did you tried to ask to change the dates, but keeping the 2 months? What did they say?

Comment: I have not. I can ask. Do you have any email/telephone where I can call?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can apply for another UK visa and would want to include an explanation of the change in plans. UK policy allows only one type of permission at a time, so the issuing post would curtail the current (and unused) visa at the time it issues another visa to your family members.